# why ttcp duplicate 4 first byte of my data?

Tags: networking

I want try to use ttcp for send udp data like below:

```
 echo 12345 | ttcp -tup 123 10.0.0.123
```

but when I see in wireshark actually sent 5 packets
in first one 12345
and in others 1234
why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following process occurs:

1. The `ttcp` program sends the data requested.
2. The `echo` program closes the input pipe.
3. The `ttcp` program shuts down the "connection", sending the additional packets that you see.

If you do `(echo 12345 ; sleep 10) | ttcp ...`, you'll see that it sends the data requests, and then 10 seconds later shuts down the connection sending the additional packets that you see.

This is substantially the same semantics as you'd have if you used TCP on a machine that supported T/TCP. The first packet send would be a SYN, but it would also contain the data (in the hopes that it could establish the connection and send the data in a single packet). If it got no reply, it would retransmit. (And retransmissions might not contain as much data, since the chance of success is lower, it makes more sense not to waste bandwidth.) If you tried to close the connection normally before it timed out, it would still linger, trying to establish the connection and send the data.

Comment: thanks and how I can perevent it?

Comment: It depends why you want to prevent it. If you just want to send raw UDP data, use something like `nc`.

Comment: in nc when i do cat filename | nc -u 1.1.1.34 223 don't back to prompt

Comment: This actually looks like a bug in `nc`! It does a `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` on the socket and then appears to expect the other side to complete the shutdown (like in TCP), which of course doesn't happen for UDP.